# Set method of TPicture property doesn't get called when the form is created

Tags: delphi, components, vcl, delphi-xe7

Here's my component overall structure:

- My Component

  - property Categories: TCollection (of TCategory)

    - TCategory

      - **property Icon: TPicture read FIcon write SetIcon;**
      - property Example: Integer read FExample write SetExample;
      - (Other category properties...)
  - (Other properties...)

In the Object Inspector of the IDE, I choose a picture and it gets serialized successfully (I checked it in form view as text). I set a breakpoint on `SetIcon` method and when I compile and run the application, it doesn't get called at all. At the same time, `SetExample` gets called right as it should.

What's wrong with the `TPicture` property?

P.S: Set method is called in IDE, but not at runtime.

Here's a MCVE of the code:

```
unit MCVE;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Classes, Vcl.Controls, Graphics, Dialogs;

type
  TMyCollectionItem = class(TCollectionItem)
  private
    FIcon: TPicture;
    procedure SetIcon(const Value: TPicture);
  public
    constructor Create(Collection: TCollection); override;
  published
    property Icon: TPicture read FIcon write SetIcon;
  end;

  TMyCollection = class(TCollection)
  end;

  TMCVE = class(TCustomControl)
  private
    FCollection: TMyCollection;
    procedure SetCollection(const Value: TMyCollection);
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
  published
    property MyCollection: TMyCollection read FCollection write SetCollection;
  end;

procedure Register;

implementation

procedure Register;
begin
  RegisterComponents('Samples', [TMCVE]);
end;

{ TMyCollectionItem }

constructor TMyCollectionItem.Create(Collection: TCollection);
begin
  inherited;
  FIcon := TPicture.Create;
end;

procedure TMyCollectionItem.SetIcon(const Value: TPicture);
begin
  ShowMessage('SetIcon is called!');
  FIcon.Assign(Value);
end;

{ TMCVE }

constructor TMCVE.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited;
  FCollection := TMyCollection.Create(TMyCollectionItem);
end;

procedure TMCVE.SetCollection(const Value: TMyCollection);
begin
  FCollection := Value;
end;

end.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For simple types like `Integer`, `Boolean`, `Double` etc., streaming operates the way you describe. The streaming framework reads the value, and calls the property setter.

For a more complex type like `TPicture`, it does not happen that way. The streaming framework cannot call the property setter. In order to do so it would need to get hold of a fully formed `TPicture`. And it doesn't know how to do that, a priori.

So what happens instead, is that the streaming framework calls the getter of the property to obtain the `TPicture` instance that your component's constructor created. And then streams in the state of the `TPicture` stored in the .dfm file.

As it happens, `TPicture` has no published properties. The picture data is saved to the .dfm file under a property named `Data`. So, where does that come from. The answer is in the overridden `DefineProperties` method. The code looks like this:

```
procedure TPicture.DefineProperties(Filer: TFiler);

  function DoWrite: Boolean;
  begin
    // .... code removed for brevity
  end;

begin
  Filer.DefineBinaryProperty('Data', ReadData, WriteData, DoWrite);
end;
```

The `WriteData` and `ReadData` methods do the streaming.

So, to recap. You asked why the setter for a `TPicture` property was not called when streaming in the picture's properties. It is not called because the picture object that you created in your constructor streams in its properties.

Comment: Thanks. So what the solution would be? I need to do something important right when the picture is set.

Comment: That's a different question. Override `TPicture.Changed`. Even at runtime, the picture can be modified without calling the property setter. For instance, you can do `Picture.LoadFromFile(...)`

Comment: Ok that's all I needed to know. Thanks David.

Comment: Don't override `TPicture.Changed()`.  Have `TMyCollectionItem` assign a handler to the `TPicture.OnChange` event instead.  When `SetIcon()` calls `FIcon.Assign(Value)`, it also triggers `OnChange`.  BTW, you have several memory leaks. `TMyCollectionItem` is missing a destructor to free `FIcon`, `TMCVE` is missing a destructor to free `FCollection`, and `TMCVE.SetCollection()` needs to call `FCollection.Assign(Value);`.

Comment: @Remy What happens if the consumer wants to use OnChange? Overriding Changed is the correct approach for a component author.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: No, it is not correct for the author. The `TPicture` belongs to `TMyCollectionItem`. Only `TMyCollectionItem` should be assigning `OnChange` directly. If users need to receive an event when images are changed, the component should expose its own custom event for that purpose. Have the `FIcon.OnChange` handler trigger a `TMCV.OnItemIconChange` event, for instance.

Comment: @Remy In the original code, the picture object is a published property.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan. That does not change what I said. `TImage.Picture` is also published, and it uses an internal `TPicture.OnChange` event handler to trigger its own change notifications. All visual components have a `Font` property, but they have an internal `TFont.OnChange` event handler. A component consumer is not supposed to use a published object-based property's events directly, as the comsumer does not know how the component is using them internally. The consumer should only use what the component itself exposes for consumers to use.

Comment: @Remy You've got this back to front. The asker is a component author. And so must not use the public events and instead must sub class and override the protected event firing methods.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85347/discussion-between-remy-lebeau-and-david-heffernan).