# Property setter never seems to fire in Lazarus?

Tags: delphi, lazarus

**Overview**

I have a `TCustomControl` I am working on in Lazarus and outside of this class I have a separate `TPersistent` class which will be used for some properties.

The `TPersistent` class when published from the `TCustomControl` should show in the Object Inspector as sub-properties as I don't want certain properties to be shown from the top level, basically this is putting some properties into its own group within the `TCustomControl`.

The structure of this code is as follows:

```
type
  TMyControlHeaderOptions = class(TPersistent)
  private
    FOnChange: TNotifyEvent;
    FHeight: Integer;
    FVisible: Boolean;
    procedure SetHeight(const Value: Integer);
    procedure SetVisible(const Value: Boolean);
  protected
    procedure Changed;
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); virtual;
    destructor Destroy; override;

    procedure Assign(Source: TPersistent); override;
    property OnChange: TNotifyEvent read FOnChange write FOnChange;
  published
    property Height: Integer read FHeight write SetHeight default 20;
    property Visible: Boolean read FVisible write SetVisible default True;
  end;

  TMyControl = class(TCustomControl)
  private
    FHeaderOptions: TMyControlHeaderOptions;
    procedure SetHeaderOptions(const Value: TMyControlHeaderOptions);
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
    destructor Destroy; override;
  published
    property Align;
    property BorderStyle default bsSingle;
    property HeaderOptions: TMyControlHeaderOptions read FHeaderOptions write SetHeaderOptions;
  end;
```

Here is the code for `TMyControlHeaderOptions`:

```
constructor TMyControlHeaderOptions.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  FHeight   := 20;
  FVisible  := True;
end;

destructor TMyControlHeaderOptions.Destroy;
begin
  inherited Destroy;
end;

// this method never fires (see TMyControl.SetHeaderOptions)
procedure TMyControlHeaderOptions.Assign(Source: TPersistent);
begin
  if (Source is TMyControlHeaderOptions) then
  begin
    FHeight   := (Source as TMyControlHeaderOptions).Height;
    FVisible  := (Source as TMyControlHeaderOptions).Visible;
  end
  else
    inherited Assign(Source);
end;

procedure TMyControlHeaderOptions.Changed;
begin
  if Assigned(FOnChange) then
  begin
    FOnChange(Self);
  end;
end;

procedure TMyControlHeaderOptions.SetHeight(const Value: Integer);
begin
  if Value <> FHeight then
  begin
    FHeight := Value;
    Changed;
  end;
end;

procedure TMyControlHeaderOptions.SetVisible(const Value: Boolean);
begin
  if Value <> FVisible then
  begin
    FVisible := Value;
    Changed;
  end;
end;
```

And the `TCustomControl` code:

```
constructor TMyControl.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner);

  FHeaderOptions    := TMyControlHeaderOptions.Create(Self);
  Self.ControlStyle := Self.ControlStyle + [csAcceptsControls];
  Self.BorderStyle  := bsSingle;
  Self.Height       := 200;
  Self.Width        := 250;
end;

destructor TMyControl.Destroy;
begin
  FHeaderOptions.Free;
  inherited Destroy;
end;

// this method never fires which is why TMyControlHeaderOptions.Assign
// never fires either. So the task is understanding and solving why this
// procedure never gets fired? 
procedure TMyControl.SetHeaderOptions(const Value: TMyControlHeaderOptions);
begin
  FHeaderOptions.Assign(Value);
end;
```

**Problem**

The property `HeaderOptions` never triggers or gets fired at designtime or runtime and I just can't understand or see why not? As you can see from the comments included in the code above `SetHeaderOptions` doesn't appear to be doing anything at all, it never responds to changes made at designtime or runtime.

I don't have Delphi installed to compare or test with but the code has been taken from custom controls I had been previously working on and I am pretty much certain it should work, I don't seem to have missed anything out that I can see. My only assumption at this point is the differences in Lazarus and Delphi and so the problem possibly lies within Lazarus?

**Question**

So my question is why does the property setter `HeaderOptions` never get fired and what can be done to make sure it does?

I sense something simple or obvious but I just cannot figure out what it is.

Comment: A property setter fires when you set that property, you never assign anything to 'HeaderOptions'.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz, The line `FHeaderOptions.Assign(Value);` in the `TMyControl.SetHeaderOptions` procedure should call the overrided `Assign` in the `TMyControlHeaderOptions` class.

Comment: the property is HeaderOptions, not FHeaderOptions.

Answer (score 3):

When you change a property inside this `TPersistent`, it fires the property setter of that particular property. It's not supposed to call the setter of the `TPersistent` itself. That only occurs in two scenarios: a) When the DFM is streamed in on creation, or b) when you manually assign a new value to the actual `TPersistent`. If you want to capture when any property is changed, you need to capture on each property individually, perhaps triggering an `OnChange` notify event which feeds back to its owner. That's actually how things such as the `TFont` or `TStrings` work.

Take a look at some of the built-in classes, such as `TFont` and `TStrings` - they use a `TNotifyEvent` named `OnChange` to handle such changes.

Comment: I wondered whether the OP was actually asking about a situation akin to this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31858026/set-method-of-tpicture-property-doesnt-get-called-when-the-form-is-created

Comment: Thanks for your feedback I will see if there is another way to capture the changes. Its just a little strange how I know in Delphi I have done it this exact way and it worked where for example `TMyControl.SetHeaderOptions` would fire but in Lazarus it does not seem to do anything.

Comment: @Craig It's the same way in Delphi. Actually, I've never used Lazarus, but surely it's the same.

Comment: That's why I am stumped, I know technically Lazarus is not an exact clone of Delphi and as such should be treat as its own but it still uses pretty much the same Pascal OOP syntax. So if it's not Lazarus then it must be my code but I am positive I am doing no different to what I would normally do in Delphi.

Comment: @Craig That can't work in either case. The actual `TPersistent` itself doesn't care what its members do. It's up to you to decide how to feed that back into its owner. Your past experience must have had some extra code which you forgot about. I personally would hate if the `TPersistent`'s property setter was triggered when one of its members changed.

Comment: Not only that, but the `TPersistent` has absolutely no knowledge of this property setter in its parent.

Comment: What Jerry is saying is right, but it's a little unclear. The streaming framework doesn't instantiate a new `TMyControlHeaderOptions` object and assign it to the `HeaderOptions` property. Instead it reads the `HeaderOptions` property, and streams the state into that object.

Answer (score -1):

I am still perplexed as to why this was not working in Lazarus as I am almost certain it did work in Delphi.

I managed to come up with a workaround in the meantime:

```
TMyControl = class(TCustomControl)
  private
    FHeaderOptions: TMyControlHeaderOptions;
    procedure HeaderOptionsChanged(Sender: TObject); // added this line
    procedure SetHeaderOptions(const Value: TMyControlHeaderOptions); // removed this procedure
  published
    property Align;
    property BorderStyle default bsSingle;
    property HeaderOptions: TMyControlHeaderOptions read FHeaderOptions write FHeaderOptions; // changed this 
  end;
```

Then added this in the constructor:

```
constructor TMyControl.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner);

  FHeaderOptions          := TMyControlHeaderOptions.Create(Self);
  FHeaderOptions.OnChange := @HeaderOptionsChanged; // added this line

  Self.ControlStyle := Self.ControlStyle + [csAcceptsControls];
  Self.BorderStyle  := bsSingle;
  Self.Height       := 200;
  Self.Width        := 250;
end;
```

Code for the new `HeaderOptionsChanged` procedure:

```
procedure TMyControl.HeaderOptionsChanged(Sender: TObject);
begin
  // header options changed
  Invalidate;
end;
```

Comment: This isn't a work-around, this is how it's supposed to be designed, as I explained in my answer. However, you've introduced two new issues. a) Why are you using `@`? That's unnecessary. And b) You shouldn't have gotten rid of the property setter, you should keep it and use `FHeaderOptions.Assign(Value);`. Things such as `TFont` and `TStrings` work precisely like this for the exact reason.

Comment: @JerryDodge in Lazarus/FPC you need to use the '@' symbol operator ;) I removed the `FHeaderOptions.Assign(Value);` because it still wouldn't fire.

Comment: I see. My point with using `Assign()` is that using direct assignment to `FHeaderOptions` is copying a pointer to potentially a different instance, not the actual value. In certain usage, this could lead to a memory leak.

Comment: *I am almost certain it did work in Delphi.* Nope. You got that wrong. Furthermore, the changes outlined here are totally wrong. You now leak instances of `TMyControlHeaderOptions`. @Jerry has it right, and you should accept his answer. -1

Comment: @DavidHeffernan where do I leak instances of `TmyControlHeaderOptions`? See original code which this is just a modified version of, the destructor releases `FHeaderOptions` there.

Comment: `property HeaderOptions: TMyControlHeaderOptions read FHeaderOptions write FHeaderOptions;` That leaks when you assign to the property. You need a setter that calls `Assign`.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan which I originally had in place but never fired, the setter never triggered, Lazarus reports no memory leaks either. In any case it's evident from all the comments and your downvote that I need to rethink what I am doing.

Comment: The setter for `HeaderOptions` is not expected to fire. I'm not sure what you are actually trying to do, but I do believe you need to step back and re-consider.

Comment: The task is to display and show sub-properties of my custom control from the object inspector, and be notified when those sub-properties have changed.

Comment: You have to use an OnChanged mechanism as per TFont and similar classes.

Comment: Have you looked at other built-in implementations like I suggested three times now? They work precisely the way that David and I are telling you. I've written plenty components from scratch, this isn't a new subject for me. Why ask a question and then insist that the answer (verified by other users) is incorrect?